# Unable to create a manual payment in Odoo 15 community edition

Tags: odoo, odoo-15, odoo-accounting

I am using Odoo 15 Community edition.
When I go to Accounting/[Customers|Vendors]/Payments and try to register a new payment, I get this python error:

> ValueError: Invalid field 'effective_date' on model 'account.payment'

Only way to get out of that screen is to discard the payment. This only happens there. I create a purchase or sale order and pay it using the Purchase or Sales module all works fine.

I tried to go in to developer mode and search for the account.payment module and indeed it does not have that field.

- How can I fix this issue?
- Can I add the field in the model?

  - if yes, which properties will be good?

Comment: Do you have any custom module? 
Also, I'm assuming you are talking about the invoicing module and not the accounting module as this one is not available in the Community Edition.
This error doesn't seem to happen when using the Community Edition on Runbot

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: Hi Levizar, thanks for replying, I am kind of confused, under apps the module is listed as Invoicing (account in purple -- the official name).

I do not have any custom module installed.
I also tried to setup a demo database in odoo.com  using Odoo 16 and I was not able to reproduce the error there. I went even further and try to find if there was any field called "effective_date" on the account.payment model but there is not. 

So I have no other ideas on how to troubleshoot this.